# What is the syntax for Building an inner class list outside of the outer class?

Tags: apex

Do I need to make a new instance of the class and then reference that first?

For example:

```
PageExtension.SortWrapper listDoingSorting = New PageExtension.SortWrapper();
listDoingSorting = New List<SortWrapper>(); //creating list to do sorting
```

Comment: can you put your understanding through some sample code

Comment: That is what I have so far. I have seen other posts on here but still confused. I have the inner class part but I am not sure how to build a list of it. and thanks @adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create an instance of the type `List<PageExtension.SortWrapper>`:

```
List<PageExtension.SortWrapper> wrappers = new List<PageExtension.SortWrapper();
```

You can also construct single instance elements and add them to the collection:

```
wrappers.add(new PageExtension.SortWrapper());
```

Or you can populate elements at run time:

```
List<PageExtension.SortWrapper> wrappers = new List<PageExtension.SortWrapper>
{
    new PageExtension.SortWrapper()
};
```

There are more syntactic options available to you, but that should give you the basic idea.

Comment: This worked great. I see that when I add an object to the list it has me reference the parent class as well Il add as the correct answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks.